# nestjs invalid algorithm error with bearer token from google

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-passport

I'm trying to secure a nestjs api project using a jwt generated by google oauth. I have the client code working and have verified with jwt.io that the jwt being generated is correct and validates ok with the client secret I have.

I have followed the guide from nestjs for implementing passport and the jwt auth guard, however all I get when I pass a bearer token to an method with the guard is `JsonWebTokenError: invalid algorithm`

The relevant code snippits:

jwt.strategy.ts

```
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: true,
      secretOrKey: privateKey,
      algorithms: ['HS256']
    });
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  async validate(payload: any) {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(+payload.sub);
    console.log(user);
    return user;
  }
}
```

jwt.auth-guard.ts

```
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  handleRequest(err, user, info, context) {
    // valid Token: empty log line
    // invalid Token: empty log line
    console.log(err, 'error');

    // valid Token: token object
    // invalid Token: false
    console.log(user, 'user');

    // valid Token: empty log line
    // invalid Token: error object from passport
    console.log(info, 'info');      <---- ERROR COMES FROM HERE

    // valid Token: no log line at all
    // invalid Token: no log line at all
    console.log(context, 'context');
    if (err || !user) {
      console.error(`JWT Authentication error: ${err}`);
      throw err || new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

auth.module.ts

```
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt', session: true }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secretOrPrivateKey: privateKey,
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: 3600,
        algorithm: 'HS256'
      }
    }),
    UsersModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem! Have came up with a solution?